# Sharing Firefox 69.0.3 (64 b) profiles between Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, firefox, windows-7

All Windows partitions are in NTFS. I need using Windows FF profile also from U FF installation.

FF profile resides at two places (why?):

```
/home/loz/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/l87wht4f.default
/home/loz/snap/firefox/common/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l87wht4f.default
```

Profile sharing entry is:

```
[Profile1]
Name=New profile
IsRelative=0
Path=/media/loz/H_2_W7/Users/Loz/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/5782g3u8.default-1499492137655
```

FF with native default profile on U functions normally, but when I try "New profile" I get the famous:

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.

No FF processes in System monitor,  .parentlock parameter deleted. In good old times when I used U 16.04 and previous version of FF - all was smooth and friendly.

@user.dz asks about "special usage case". Please, specify what is of importance here. I have the following exhaustive list of add-ons in my W7 FF profile:

1. 1-Click YouTube Video Downloader
2. Audio Downloader Prime
3. Avast Online Security
4. Bitwarden - Free Password Manager
5. Bookmark Manager and Viewer

6.Bookmark search plus 2

7. Browsec VPN - Free and Unlimited VPN
8. Copy ShortURL
9. Evernote Web Clipper
10. Fess Google Bookmark Extension
11. Grammarly for Firefox
12. Hoxx VPN Proxy
13. iShortener
14. Media Converter and Muxer - Audio Tools
15. Simple Translate
16. StoreTranslate
17. URL Shortner + QR Code Generator
18. Web Scraper
19. YouTube Best Video Downloader 2
20. YouTube Video and Audio Downloader (Dev Edt.)
21. ZenMate VPN - Best Cyber Security & Unblock

What else can be of importance as "special"?
Any hints?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Why not using firefox sync service? privacy matters?

Comment: I don't think you need the `.cache` when I synced my profiles manually between Win7 and Ubuntu or between Ubuntu and Ubuntu, then nothing seemed missing without the cache.

Comment: @user.dz - My FF profile is HUGE - more than 3 Gbytes (mainly bookmarks). To synchronize it through not very broad Internet channels may take much time and lack of reliability - as I am afraid...

Comment: @Carolus - thank you for your reply! In those good old days my scheme also worked pretty well. Maybe I've got into problem due the newest versions of Ubuntu and/or FF...

Comment: @Viraliy, you have special usage case, such details should be added to the question. Add any relevant details that out of regular. So our friends here can help with special solution too for your case. Are you using any add-on to manage them or other add-on with big data too?

Comment: I lost hope to obtain a solution concerning sharing the FF profile and switched to the sync method. Even with my huge profile - it seems to work OK. Though, initial sync establishing took about 3-4 hours...